# How to get a batch file to handle spaces in file names?

Tags: batch-file, filenames

I am using the following batch file to make a zip file for each xml in a folder:

```
FOR %%f in ("C:\files\*.xml") DO 7za.exe a C:\files\zips\%%~nf.zip (%%f)
```

However if the file name has a space in it (`test plop.xml`) then the batch file does not work. It seems to split the name and thinks it is 2 files.

How to modify the batch file so that it properly handles file names with spaces?

Comment: Have you tried putting double-quotes around the file name? eg.: `("%%f")`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try placing quotes around the output file name.

Change

```
FOR %%f in ("C:\files*.xml") DO 7za.exe a C:\files\zips\%%~nf.zip (%%f)
```

to:

```
FOR %%f in ("C:\files*.xml") DO 7za.exe a "C:\files\zips\%%~nf.zip" (%%f)
```

May also be the variable %%f, may need to place quotes around this as well.